# How to diagonalize the sum of outer products

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition

Consider the following sequence of matrices $S_n\triangleq I +\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{v}_i \mathbf{v}_i^{\operatorname{T}}$, where $(\mathbf{v}_i) \subset\mathbb{R}^m$. Given that $S_n$ is a symetric positive definite matrix, there exists an orthogonal and diagonal matrix $P_n$ and $D_n$, respectively, such that $S_n = P^{\operatorname{T}}_n D_n P_n$.

My question is the following; does there exist simple expressions for $P_{n+1}$ and $D_{n+1}$ as functions of $(\mathbf{v}_{n+1},S_n,S^{-1}_n,P_n,D_n)$?

I was hoping to find something similar to the [Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) which gives the expression of the inverse of $S_{n+1}$ as \begin{align}S^{-1}_{n+1} = S^{-1}_n - \frac{S_n^{-1}\mathbf{v}_{n+1}\mathbf{v}^{\operatorname{T}}_{n+1}S^{-1}_{n}}{1 + \mathbf{v}_{n+1}^{\operatorname{T}} S^{-1}_n \mathbf{v}_{n+1}}. \end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have the ambiguity of ordering the eigenvectors/eigenvaules.  If you ignore this ambiguity, then it is just the [Bunch-Nielsen-Sorensen formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunch%E2%80%93Nielsen%E2%80%93Sorensen_formula), plus finding the eigenvalues of $D_n+\mathbf{uu}^T$.

So you want to solve the characteristic equation $\det (D+\mathbf{uu}^T-\lambda I)=0$, which is
$$
\prod_{i=1}^m (D_{ii}-\lambda)+\sum_{i=1}^m u_i^2\prod_{j\neq i}(D_{jj}-\lambda)=0.
$$
(this comes from $\det(A+\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^T)=(1+\mathbf{v}^TA^{-1}\mathbf{u})\det A$ applied to $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{u}$ and $A=D-\lambda I$)

In particular, if the diagonal of $D$ is increasing $D_{11}\leq D_{22}\leq\dots$ then the roots $\lambda_i$ satisfies $D_{ii}\leq\lambda_i\leq D_{i+1,i+1}$ for $i<m$ and the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_m$ is bounded by $D_{mm}\leq\lambda_m\leq D_{mm}+\sum u_i^2$.

Comment: Thanks. This is very close to what I want, but the formula requires the eigenvalue of $A$ (or $S_{n+1}$ in my case). Furthermore, $S_n$ is not diagonal in my case.

Comment: But you know the matrix $P_n$ that conjugates $S_n$ to diagonal.  Apply that to $v_{n+1}$ too and you get $S_{n+1}\sim D_n+\mathbf{uu}^T$.  I've also added a few words about the characteristic equation in this case but yes, you don't really have a general formula for that.

Comment: If you have a general formula for finding the eigenvalues of this problem, then you would have solve eigenvalues for every symmetric matrix, because up to adding/subtracting suitable multiple of identity, every symmetric matrix can be reached this way with suitable sequence of $\mathbf{v}_i$.